# RAP Key Binding CTRL + S calls Browser save

Tags: eclipse, browser, binding, save, key

I'm using RAP 2.3 and added a Key binding like that:

```
    <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
      <key
            commandId="mysave"
            schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
            sequence="M1+S">
      </key>
   </extension>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="de.application.ui.SaveHandler"
            id="mysave"
            name="name">
      </command>
   </extension
```

But when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in my Application the Browser-SaveAction is called and not my SaveHandler. Does anybody have an idea how to fix that?

Comment: This looks similar: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/248763/

Comment: I tried it the same way, but it doesn't work. If I use for example M1+K my command is executed...